# Unhashable type: ‘list’, trying to subtract a list from a list

Tags: python

I am trying to run code which can find installed packages within my Python environment and install those which are not found within `requirements.txt`. I keep getting an error on the line:

```py
required = {requirements}
```

Here is my code so far:

```
with open ('requirements.txt', "r") as myfile:
        requirements = myfile.read().splitlines()
        #requirements=myfile.readlines()
        #requirements=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        print(requirements)
#file_read('test.txt')

required = {requirements}
installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing = required - installed

if missing:
    python = sys.executable
    subprocess.check_call([python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', *missing], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
else:
    print("prerequisites found")
```

I keep getting the 'Unhashable' error which I know has something to do with the extracted list but I am not sure how to tackle the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `requirements` is a `list`, and it seems you want to make it a `set`. Try `required  = {*requirements}`

Comment: Maybe you wanted `required = set(requirements)`

Comment: Matthias’ solution worked wonders! Thank you for the help and everyone else that helped!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to add the single list object to the set. Lists are mutable and not hashable, so it fails. Instead, you want to put the values of the list into the set. Either `set(requirements)`, `{*requirements}` or `{line for line in requirements}` will do.

```
>>> requirements = "foo\nbar\nbaz".splitlines()
>>> requirements
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> {requirements}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> set(requirements)
{'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```